# Any window.append method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, append

Good day,

I am trying to add/append something in my page when I click on `window.print()`.

Any method can do this?

For example:

```
window.append('<p>new thing here</p>');
window.print();
```

Maybe you will ask me why not I write the `<p>new thing here</p>` in my jsp page, so that the `window.print()` will print them out. My concern is, I have thousand of jsp using this `window.print()`, If I add in every page, its look like not a good way, and hard to do future maintenance as well.

Comment: You can use `$('body').append('<p>new thing here</p>');`

Comment: @SuperUser , how if I wan to append it on top of page?

Comment: If you want to add something to the page that's only visible when the page is printed, use an `@media` rule in CSS. It's a much better method than any JS hack to hook to a print related event

Comment: Check it on answer

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, if I use `@media` rule, means I need to write `<p>new thing here</p>` in the jsp, my concern is I have thousand of jsp using this window.print(), If I add in every page, its look like not a good way, and hard to do future maintenance as well. Or in `@media` rule, I can import jsp?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$('body').append('<p>new thing here</p>');
```

if you want to add it on top of the page then you can use `.prepend()`

```
$('body').prepend('<p>new thing here</p>');
```